# Sass with react render not working

Tags: reactjs, sass, ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to react and have been playing around with it. This might be basic so please bear with me on this.

Basically, I have been setting up my environment (React+Babel+webpack). I am currently in the process of using sass with react but I have no idea why this isn't working.

**Webpack config**

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/client.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
                }
            },
            { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }, {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
               loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                'style', // backup loader when not building .css file
                'css!sass' // loaders to preprocess CSS
    )
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    },
   plugins:  [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
       ] 
};
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>React</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="client.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Client.js/Entry point**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./pages/css/bootstrap.min.css"; //Added bootstrap css and it was working fine
import "./pages/client.scss";


const app = document.getElementById('example');

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1 className="hello">Yayyy</h1>,
            example);
```

**client.scss**

```
.hello {
    h1 {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help and would be happy if am directed towards some good resources to look into as well for starters.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error, or is it just not applying the styles?

Comment: @JoshuaComeau No errors. It's not applying the styles.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I see what's going on!

Webpack normally works by bundling all your modules (be they JS, CSS, whatever) into one big JS file. ExtractTextPlugin, however, exists to bundle something separately, in text format.

This is used when you want to create an external .css file. If you go this route, you'd include a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file">` in your HTML file.

The more traditional route is to treat the SCSS just like you're treating the CSS. Then, you can just `import` it in JS :)

Example:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'style!css!sass'
}
```

I'm far from a webpack expert, but I believe this will solve your problem :)

Comment: You mean if I just drop off the ExtractTextPlugin, I can just import the scss file and it would work fine?

Comment: Well I already have tried that before, but no luck. No errors, and not applying any style.

Comment: How about leaving the ExtractTextPlugin, building it (with `webpack -p`), and checking the rendered files? There should be a `.css` file in the build directory, and you can add that as a `<link>` in your HTML

Comment: I managed to resolve it by configuring the webpack from scratch. Apparently, not sure though the problem was that I wasn't adding the link in the html. I should up your answer. Thank you. Also, If you could guide me about the best practices of folder structure for react? I'd appreciate if you could point me into the right direction for that (Test driven development)